# Encrypting a full 8TB/10TB drive with VeraCrypt

Tags: disk-encryption, clonezilla, veracrypt

So deciding to encrypt a full 8TB/10TB drive to **test** and see how it performs.

1. I estimate around +/- 2 days to encrypt 2TB, therefore 8TB drive will take around 8 days, can anyone confirm if they have tried this? and if the time is close to being correct?
2. What will it be like Encrypting/Decrypting 8TB/10TB everytime..performance wise? and how long will it take to encrypt/decrypt the 8TB/10TB drive everytime after inserting a password for outer/inner volume?
3. Can decrypting the cloned drive (that was cloned with Clonezilla) be successful and the data still be **intact and readable**?

VeraCrypt version 1.17
with maximum security encryption method.

Comment: +1 but you might consider combining 1 and 2, and don't ask for people's experiences, an answer can have better (non-anecdotal) sources that way.

Comment: Q1 relates to the time taken to properly encrypting or 'initially encrypting' the drive from start to finish and Q2 relates to the time taken to encrypt/decrypt the whole drive at password insertion time.

Answer (score 1):

I know the above question is old but I like to add some info.

**Yes**, you can encrypt large encrypted containers of example 4TB using AES 256 or other and you will have a pretty decent speed and example are able to play 4k videos from inside your encrypted folder without any problems, even on a home lan from hard disk via LAN to your tv.

Also you don't need anything stronger than AES 256 and it also gives a good speed.

The speed of the encrypted file container do not, to my knowledge, change and its the same even if it's a 100MB container or a 4TB container.

However it take longer to "open" an encrypted 4TB container and example from 20 sec to 2 minutes depending on your system, while a 100MB encrypted container take 1 sec.

Once the file container is open and mounted in VeraCrypt then the 4TB container will feel more or less like an ordinary hard disk. However be aware that file transfer and file read are slower than a non encrypted hard disk.

All files you copy into the file container is automatic put in the encrypted storage, and all files you take out of it is automatic no longer encrypted.

**How long does it take to encrypt larger encrypted containers?**

If you make a new 3TB encrypted AES 256bit VeraCrypt container and encrypt and your HD is connected via usb 3.1 usb-c and can do 250mb/s  ( example with an LaCie 8TB drive ) then you can encrypt with about 200MB/s and then 3TB encrypted file container take about 3 hours to encrypt and make.

But to copy data from your computer and into your new encrypted folder is slower.

While I encrypt another container on my hard disk, I tried to copy some data to it at the same time, I am able to copy new files to the mounted container with about 66mb/s so the transfer speed is pretty low compared to non encrypted hard disk.

This might speed up once I finish encryption, but you get an idea it take time.
The same goes if you encrypt your windows hard disk then it will slow down the read/write speed of windows quite a lot. ( on an SSD my guess is 35-50% slower but this is just a guess).

**Regarding what software to use when making backup and synchronization**:

I highly recommend the OLD but good free windows software named 
[SyncToy 2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155).

I know from experience that it work 100% and are able to sync more than 4TB file containers without problems.. Many commercial sync software typical crash or become unstable with such large amount of data and large amount of files ).

BE AWARE it matter if you run the program with admin rights or not.. so do a small test first, since in one of the modes you can overwrite and replace sync data, while in the other it give an error and skip the files sometimes.

I do however not recommend to make 1 big encrypted file container, example of 4TB or 8 TB large.  Reason are to copy example 4TB of data from your computer and into your file container take like 5 - 7 days for 4TB data, so it's better to make example 3 or 4 container of example 2TB of data; One for personal photos/documents, videos, games, etc.

That way it's more easy to do backups of specific things on smaller hard disks and they mount faster and so on. Also if something goes wrong or the hard disk have errors on it, then you won't lose everything.

You can make VeraCrypt automatic mount all the above containers automatic on startup of your computer so think of it as 4 new drives for a specific kind of data.

Advice: Your most valuable data should be stored on 3 different hard disks so you never lose your private photos and such. Life is long you regret it if you lose such data. Maybe ask a friend to keep one harddisk in his home and vice versa just in case of fire or theft.

Advice with VeraCrypt: It's possible to copy large file containers of example 4TB from one hard disk to the other.. however use the above program and be prepared it will take several days..

You an ofcours also mount two different veracrypt containers and copy files direct from inside one container to the other container. But it might just be more easy to copy the entire container in one go than one file at a time.
(If you copy large files or a lot of files, then use a sync software like the one above.. don't use windows std copy/paste; it's not reliable).

Answer (score 0):

A1: Time to do 'encrypt'/'decrypt' of a full container (partition) in place (aka, not loosing data) can take a really long, long time... if partition is empty, better do it the other way (not in place) and tell it not to do on full, after when mounted, use a tool to fill free space as a backgorund task (create a dummy file, fill it till partition is full, then delete it).

A2: Encryption/Decription on a 'mounted' is done on the fly and only blocks that are read/write are decripted/encripted... so if CPU is fast enough (and not overload by other processes) and HDD is slow enough, it will have no impact on speed... but if HDD let's say can Write at 1.3GiB/s (fastest PCIe solid state memory cards, upto 1TiB) and CPU can only encrypt/decrypt at 100MiB/s, there will be a very great impact on speed.

A3: To use CloneZilla and similars, the best is to first use (may need some install on LiveCD and that can be long proccess) VeraCrypt to mount the drive, then do the Clone so clone tool will see it as non-encrypted... remember (for security) to store the image on a 'secure' place, aka another encrypted partition on external media mounted, or whatever tou consider 'secure'... to restore it... do the oposite... mount VeraCrypt and restore there, then (if needed) use VeraCrypt rescu to restore boot, etc.

A3*: Another option is to clone the encrypted partition without mounting it, but that way it is needed more than the full size, since free space will not be known without mounting... i recomend mounting prior cloning/restoring.